# Maven config for RESTEasy 2.2.0.GA

Tags: maven-2, resteasy

I can't seem to find RESTEasy 2.2.0.GA in the JBoss repos. Anyone know of a repos in which I can find this version of RESTEasy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atlassian repository has a copy:

https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/resteasy/

Answer (score 0):

It's in there, now at least.

You can search the repo here: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html